# PySpark using OR operator in filter

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, operators

I have an array that I am indexing to filter for data from cities of California.

This filter works:
`raw_df_2 = raw_df_1.filter(array_contains(col("country.state.city"), 'San Diego'))`

However, when I expand to include other cities:

```
raw_df_2 = raw_df_1.filter(array_contains(col("country.state.city"), 'San Diego') || array_contains(col("country.state.city"), 'Sacramento') || array_contains(col("country.state.city"), 'Los Angeles'))
```

I get `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

I have also tried

```
raw_df_2 = raw_df_1.filter(array_contains(col("country.state.city"), 'San Diego' || 'Sacramento' || 'Los Angeles'))
```

but this also returns `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

What is the correct usage of the OR operator in Spark to filter data from Californian cities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logical OR uses a **single vertical bar** (`|`).

```
raw_df_2 = raw_df_1.filter(array_contains(col("country.state.city"), 'San Diego') | array_contains(col("country.state.city"), 'Sacramento') | array_contains(col("country.state.city"), 'Los Angeles'))
```